# php jquery count down timer script

Tags: php, jquery

i have one count down timer using    http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay,format: 'HMS'});
```

this works fine.

but for one year, as i can see in code that

> austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);

is generating last date.

my last date is coming from PHP and i want to change the above line so that last date will be calculated from one of PHP variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
austDay = new Date('<?php echo date("F d, Y H:i:s", time()); ?>');
```